# Does auto.arima of the forecast package deal with seasonality and trend automatically

Tags: r, time-series

I'm reading some code involving `auto.arima` method from the `forecast` package in R. What I'm curious is whether there is a necessity for decomposing the time series data into seasonal, trend and stochastic compoents before passing to the `auto.arima` method, or is it automatically handled by the functionality of the method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the aim of `auto.arima` is for fitting ARIMA models automatically. You do not need to decompose your time series before hand. See how the algorithm works here https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-r.html.

You may still want to look at arguments available in the `auto.arima` function, and you may want to change default maximum values for `p`, `q`, and `d`, etc.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for as an answer. Thanks